# Modal not opens after sleep mode or inactivity in the app in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

I am using Modal to open the Terms in my app. Here I can open and close the modal without any issues.

But if I open the modal once and then not do anything inside the app and it goes to sleep mode. Then on the mobile, it will shows the app and I can't able to see the modal window and also If I again try to open the modal it not respond?

Any workaround solutions?

Answer (score 1):

There is an idea, you could try to use [Appstate](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate) to handle it.

Detect the app comes to foreground, and then close the Modal, maybe it could works?

This is example of appstate (functional) on document, close the modal at the console line.(If you use class component, is the same theory use on [document](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate) class example)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { AppState, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const AppStateExample = () => {
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState(AppState.currentState);

  useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);

    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);
    };
  }, []);

  const _handleAppStateChange = nextAppState => {
    if (appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === "active") {
      console.log("App has come to the foreground!");  // Close the Modal here 
    }
    setAppState(nextAppState);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Current state is: {appState}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
});

export default AppStateExample;
```

Take it a try.

Comment: I have checked the appstate. If the app state is inactive i have set the modalVisible to false. But I am facing the same issue after this. Any examples?